# Boolean product of matrix A

Tags: c, matrix, boolean

Let A be a matrix of order 3x3. Determine how many different matrices can be formed by Boolean Product of matrix A.

This what I have come up with:

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {

    int matrixA[3][3];
    int matrixB[3][3];
    int result[3][3];
    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;

    printf("\n Boolean Power of Matrix\n");

    printf("\n Matrix of order 3x3\n\n");



    for(b=0;b<3;b++)
    {
        for(a=0;a<3;a++)
        {
        printf("Insert  Column %d Row %d : ",a+1,b+1);
        scanf("%d",&matrixA[a][b]);
        matrixB[a][b]=matrixA[a][b];

        }

    }

    printf("\n");


    for(b=0;b<3;b++)
    {
        for(a=0;a<3;a++)
        {
        printf("  %d",matrixB[a][b]);

        }
        printf("\n");

    }

    printf("Boolean Power Matrix of order 3x3\n");


    result[0][0]=(matrixB[0][0]*matrixA[0][0])+(matrixB[0][1]*matrixA[1]        [0])+(matrixB[0][2]*matrixA[2][0]);
    if (result[0][0]==2 || result[0][0]==3)
    {
        result[0][0]=1;
    }
    result[0][1]=(matrixB[0][0]*matrixA[0][1])+(matrixB[0][1]*matrixA[1][1])+(matrixB[0][2]*matrixA[2][1]);
    if(result[0][1]==2 || result[0][1]==3)
    {
        result[0][1]=1;
    }
    result[0][2]=(matrixB[0][0]*matrixA[0][2])+(matrixB[0][1]*matrixA[1][2])+(matrixB[0][2]*matrixA[2][2]);
    if(result[0][2]==2 || result[0][2]==3)
    {
        result[0][2]=1;
    }
    result[1][0]=(matrixB[1][0]*matrixA[0][0])+(matrixB[1][1]*matrixA[1][0])+(matrixB[1][2]*matrixA[2][0]);
    if(result[1][0]==2 || result[1][0]==3)
    {
        result[1][0]=1;
    }
    result[1][1]=(matrixB[1][0]*matrixA[0][1])+(matrixB[1][1]*matrixA[1][1])+(matrixB[1][2]*matrixA[2][1]);
    if(result[1][1]==2 || result[1][1]==3)
    {
        result[1][1]=1;
    }
    result[1][2]=(matrixB[1][0]*matrixA[0][2])+(matrixB[1][1]*matrixA[1][2])+(matrixB[1][2]*matrixA[2][2]);
    if(result[1][2]==2 || result[1][2]==3)
    {
        result[1][2]=1;
    }

    result[2][0]=(matrixB[2][0]*matrixA[0][0])+(matrixB[2][1]*matrixA[1][0])+(matrixB[2][2]*matrixA[2][0]);
    if(result[2][0]==2 || result[2][0]==3)
    {
        result[2][0]=1;
    }
    result[2][1]=(matrixB[2][0]*matrixA[0][1])+(matrixB[2][1]*matrixA[1][1])+(matrixB[2][2]*matrixA[2][1]);
    if(result[2][1]==2 || result[2][1]==3)
    {
        result[2][1]=1;
    }
    result[2][2]=(matrixB[2][0]*matrixA[0][2])+(matrixB[2][1]*matrixA[1][2])+(matrixB[2][2]*matrixA[2][2]);
    if(result[2][2]==2 || result[2][2]==3)
    {
        result[2][2]=1;
    }


    for(b=0;b<3;b++)
    {
        for(a=0;a<3;a++)
        {
        printf(" %d ",result[a][b]);

        }
        printf("\n");

    }



    return 0;
    }
```

but i still does not know how to find the boolean power.

Comment: i know, i just need some help thats all. its ok if u dont want to help.my fault. :)

Comment: There's still plenty of time - try to come up with a solution and if it doesn't work - edit your question with the code

Comment: this is the one i've come up with..can u see whats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use std::set to have a collection of a unique number at any given position.

Answer (score 0):

By *Boolean Product of matrix A* you seem to mean the boolean product of matrix A and matrix A, since, as you know, it takes two to make a product.

You correctly, albeit laboriously, implemented the computation of the boolean matrix product. Now, in order to determine how many different matrices can be formed, we have to generate all possible different 3x3 matrices with values 0 and 1 (of which there are 2<sup>3x3</sup>), compute the product, store the result somehow, and count how many different results come out.
Of course it would be wearisome to input all the matrices by hand; so for a start, wrap a loop around the computation and generate the different matrices automatically:

```
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 1<<3*3; ++i)
  {
    for (b=0; b<3; b++)
        for (a=0; a<3; a++)
        { 
        /* drop the manual input
        printf("Insert  Column %d Row %d : ",a+1,b+1);
        scanf("%d",&matrixA[a][b]);
        */
          matrixA[a][b]=i>>a+b*3&1;
          matrixB[a][b]=matrixA[a][b];
        }
    …
```